# What can I use to replace a Shimano Deore LX RD-M581?

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, maintenance, derailleur-rear, diy

I've got a trusty Marin East Peak XC from 2008, but the rear derailleur's adjustment screws have all sheared and I need to replace it. The derailleur is a Shimano Deore LX RD-M581, but I can't find any exact replacements available.

How can I find a derailleur that will work?

I've found this extra info for my bike:

- Rear cogs: 9 speed, 11-32
- Chainring: 44/32/22
- So the total capacity required is 43
- I'm not quite sure if the current is GS or SGS

I've seen some advice that I can could get the right modern Shimano derailleur with 7 or 8 speeds, like an Alvio RD-M4000? I'm not particularly fussed about ultra-high quality or anything, I just need something that'll work well. I'm also a student though and can't really afford to screw it up and buy multiple versions.

[image: Current derailleur (not pretty I know, its a little goosed)]

Comment: You were correct about the required total capacity

Answer (score 1):

You can in fact use any modern Shimano derailleur for 7, 8 or 9 speeds that meets the total capacity and largest sprocket requirements. The reason is that Shimano used the same *cable actuation ratio* (ratio of cable length pulled to lateral cage movement) for MTB groups below 10 speeds.

If you want a derailleur that works as well as possible, get the current highest level 9 speed option. That would be the Alivio RD-M4000 which accommodates 32 to 36t largest sprocket and total capacity of 45. Rear derailleur specs are here: https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/spec/MTB/Rear%20Derailleur. You can look up various options.

Note: when I accessed that page there appeared to be many errors, so Shimano might be in the process of an update. Correct info can be found in the archive PDF files here: https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/archive.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: Calling Alivio the highest level 9 speed option might be a little confusing to some readers. Maybe "highest 9 speed option currently available at retailers" would be better?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to stay with Deore, I still see M591 and M592 9-speed Deore rear derailleurs in the shops (a direct successor to your M581). Those are older series, but will be Deore-level. You want the SGS version. Even my old M772 Shadow XT appears to be available. That works to me very well.